# Changing enum value with index number

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class VariableDelegate : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public enum Day
    {
        Morning,
        Afternoon,
        Evening
    }

    public Day day;

    public Day AdjustDay
    {
        get
        {
            return day;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != day)
            {
                day = value;
                Debug.Log(day);
            }
        }
    }
    
    [ContextMenu("RandomDay")]
    void RandomDay()
    {
        AdjustDay = (Day)2;
    }
}
```

if I do      `AdjustDay = (Day)2;` i am able to change it to evening. However, if I do       `AdjustDay = (Day)Random.Range(0,2);` then it doesn't work. What I want to do is to random a number(since the enum has an index), then change the AdjustDay value. If the random number can start from the min value of the enum, and the max value is the length of the enum that will be great.

Comment: ["it doesn't work" is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: The max value in `Random.Range(int min, int max)` [is exclusive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html), you probably want `(Day)Random.Range(0,3)`. (note, however, that in the float overload `Random(float min, float max)` the max value is inclusive, so be careful with which version you're using)

Comment: @Magnetron basically already has the answer for you .. API is often your first best friend ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it this way:

```
void RandomDay()
{
   var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Day));
   AdjustDay = values.GetValue(Random.Range(0,values.GetLength(0))));
}
```

With help of  `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Day))` you can get whole range of values.

Comment: it didn't work at first, but then I change it to 
  AdjustDay = (Day)DayData.GetValue(Random.Range(0,DayData.Length)); 
then it works. Thank you